# Dynamically change the color button background to darker according to its parent background color

Tags: css, sass

I am creating a page which has different background colors for different products and there will be a button which redirects to the other product.

I want the background of the button should be darker than the background color

```css
.a {
  background-color: #cc99ff;
}

.b {
  background-color: #9d0059;
}

.c {
  background-color: #cc3f10;
}

button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: white;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <img alt="img">
  <button>Test</button></div>
<div class="b">
  <img alt="img">
  <button>Test</button></div>
<div class="c">
  <img alt="img">
  <button>Test</button></div>
```

[image]

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: make the button to have a semi transparent black color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `background-color:  transparent;` to  `background-color:  rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);`.

You can adjust the opacity accordingly

```css
.a {
  background-color: #309549;
}

.b {
  background-color: #9d0059;
}

.c {
  background-color: #cc3f10;
}

button {
  background-color:  rgba(0,0,0, 0.4); /*Changed*/
  border-color: white;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <img alt="img">
  <button>Test</button></div>
<div class="b">
  <img alt="img">
  <button>Test</button></div>
<div class="c">
  <img alt="img">
  <button>Test</button></div>
```

Comment: Or if you want the button lighter the inverse could be used which still offers a transparent background but with a white overlay. `background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach, using CSS variables, calc(), and rgba colors.

```css
:root{
  --red-main: 28;
  --green-main: 150;
  --blue-main: 130;
}

.container {
    background-color:
 rgb(
     var(--red-main),
     var(--green-main),
     var(--blue-main)
 );
}

.darker-bg{
   background-color:
 rgb(
     calc(var(--red-main) - 40),
     calc(var(--green-main) - 20),
     calc(var(--blue-main) - 20)
 );
}

/* Just so things looks nicer, not relevant to your question */
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
}

* {  
   padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>

    <body>
      <main class="container">
        <h1>Hello World !</h1>
        <btn class="darker-bg">My bg is automatically darker</btn>
      </main>
    </body>
</html>
```